# Create edges database based on similar id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, edges

I have a mondgodb used with pymongo and a entry looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "52065432c36b44162f56f4a7" ),
  "user_id" : "22614761",
  "longitude" : 25.394902576,
  "created_time" : "1376144888",
  "latitude" : 36.476277607,
  "id" : "519463433050680017_22614761" }
```

I want to find all data that have similar `user_id` and store their `id` in a new database. E.g. one newly created entry:

```
{"target":"519463433050680017_22614761", "source" : "518989990404955532_361611158"}
```

I tried the following code but the outer loop stucks to the first value.

```
a = db.col.find()
b = db.col.find()
for i in a:
    for q in b:
        if i['_id'] <>  q['_id'] and i['user_id'] == q['user_id']:
            edges.insert({'source':i['user_id'],'target': q['user_id']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I was able to solve it with the following code. The `a` and `b` were pymongo cursors which for some reason (I would be glad to hear if somebody knows) didn't behave as dictionaries.

```
a = db.col.find()
bjects = []
for object in a:
       objects.append(object)


for i in objects:
    for q in objects:
        if i['_id'] <>  q['_id'] and i['user_id'] == q['user_id']:
            edges.insert({'source':i['id'],'target': q['id']})
```

Answer (score 1):

The .find() returns a single iterator, a=b - assuming that's actually supposed to be b=a - just sets it up under a different name, both loops are consuming from the same in-memory object.

do a = db.col.find() and b = db.col.find() to get independent iterators.

Comment: I had tried that already. Although I get two different objects: `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10132b710> <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10132b750>` I don't know why this doesn't work as well.

Comment: @DDL449 can you update the question with the version with both `.find()` calls? As written, apart from the `a=b/b=a` thing, the outer loop would only get the first item anyway, the inner loop would exhaust the rest.